# I made a custom formula for conditional formatting in excel which is working perfectly but it doesn't work the same way in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

So I have 3 sheets in excel, 1 with some info that I need to use, and 2 "maps", one of the maps has the codes from Sheet1 in it, the other one has names but other than that the text they are identical.

I'll call the first sheet (with the info) InfoSheet, the map with the codes Map1, and the map with the names Map2.

Now I need the cells in Map2 to format and change cell color if the code for that cell from Map1 is also present in InfoSheet, if not to keep the same color,
I managed to do this by using a New rule under conditional formatting, "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" and used the formula:

`=NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP('Map1'!$N$61,InfoSheet!$E:$E,1,FALSE)))`, then selected a color and everything works just fine...

Now I need to do the same but I google sheets and I can't figure it out how to add the same conditional formatting with that rule, cause from what I tried the formula isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Since you refer to a different tab/sheet you have to use the `INDIRECT` function.

Please try the following formula

```
=NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(INDIRECT("Map1!$N$61"),INDIRECT("InfoSheet!$E:$E"),1,FALSE)))
```

Functions used:

- [`INDIRECT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377)